# WCF Authentication & Authorization using Windows Identity Foundation

Tags: wcf, wif

I am working on a asp.net mvc application and a WCF service which will be accessed by the mvc app. I am using WIF based STS website to do authentication and authorization on mvc app. Now I want to achieve the same thing on each method of web service.

I am thinking whether I can pass the claims info I have in MVC App to the WCF to do authentication and authorization. I dont want WCF to contact STS again for authentication. I cannot use windows authentication. I also want to make use of  ClaimsAuthorizationManager to achieve this.

If anybody has some about it please share. It will be a big help for me.

Joe

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is take the claims set and assign it to the proxy to "pass-through" to the service. How would you expect the token to passed over the wire and how would you expect it to be signed?

Comment: What bindings are you planning to use between the UI and WCF service layer?

Answer (score 0):

1. If your WCF Service is not REST, then maybe you can find the answer here [Identity Delegation with AD FS 2.0 Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-identity-delegation-step-by-step-guide%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
2. If your WCF Service is RESTful, check-out the example 8-ActiveRestClientFederation (download from [Identity Guidance](https://claimsid.codeplex.com/releases/view/67606)); Dominick Baier's guide [Token-based Authentication for WCF REST Service](http://leastprivilege.com/2011/11/15/token-based-authentication-for-wcf-httprest-services-authentication/) and from Stefan's blog [Secure your REST-based WCF service with WIF](http://www.jayway.com/2012/01/05/secure-your-rest-based-wcf-service-with-wif-part-1/).

Hope this helps.